# Send Events to Google Analytics for Gmail Incoming Emails

Tags: email, google-analytics, gmail

I'm trying to figure out how to send events to Google Analytics for Gmail incoming emails.

Ideally I would like to send the events to Google Analytics based on Gmail labels or any other filtering mechanism (email subject, sender etc).

I thought that in simplest scenario triggering webpage like https://my.site/gmail-events when email arrives to your Gmail mailbox shouldn't be hard to implement, but was wrong.

**gmail-events**

---

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script src="/js/analytics.js"></script>
      <script>ga('send', 'event', 'gmail event category', 'gmail event action', 'gmail event label')</script>
   </body>
</html>
```

---

I am aware of tracking outgoing emails technics such as placing image tag within the email and send an event once recipient opens it. But can't find solution for incoming emails landing to my Gmail.

I am opened to any suggestions and implementations (maybe there are Chrome extension that already handles this easily).

Answer (score 1):

Tracking incoming emails is going to require a bit of creativity.  There is nothing out of the box for this but if i was going to do it here is how i would approach it.

I would set up a script runing on a server with access to my email account.  I would have it run say ever five minutes looking for new emails.   If it spotted a new email i would have it send a hit to Google analytics directly though the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en)  personally i would log it as an event email received.

Its actually a very good idea i can see the value in tracking in coming mails for the support department or customer service.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I want to track incoming emails. Looks like email tracking helps with outgoing emails only, since it requires to place an image tag within the email.

Comment: Sorry i missed that Check the edit this is a nice idea.

Comment: You realize i am going to have to write a tutorial on this.

Comment: That would be awesome :)